# Displaying SVG Paths in JavaFX / javafx.iio.ImageLoaderFactory is not accessible

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I'm trying to display SVG Paths in JavaFX, but it didn't work by using the SVGPath class. Apparently the class can only handle path strings, so I tried this method to read an SVG file and extract the path:

```
    private SVGPath convertToPath(Node n) throws IOException {
    
    final SVGPath path = new SVGPath();
    path.setStrokeWidth(0.1);
    path.setStroke(Color.web("#FF0000"));
    path.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    
    DOMImplementation domImpl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
    Document document = domImpl.createDocument("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg", null);
    SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);       
    
    var a = n.getAttributes();
    
    if(a != null) {
        var style = a.getNamedItem("style");
        
        if(style != null)
            path.setStyle(style.getNodeValue());
        
    }
    
    switch(n.getNodeName()) {
        case "path":            
            var d = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("d").getNodeValue();
            path.setContent(d);
        break;
        
        case "rect":                
            var svg = svgGenerator.getShapeConverter().toSVG(new GeneralPath(
                    new Rectangle(
                            (int) Math.round( Double.valueOf(a.getNamedItem("x").getNodeValue())),
                            (int) Math.round( Double.valueOf(a.getNamedItem("y").getNodeValue())), 
                            (int) Math.round( Double.valueOf(a.getNamedItem("width").getNodeValue())),
                            (int) Math.round( Double.valueOf(a.getNamedItem("height").getNodeValue())))));  
            
             svg = svgGenerator.getShapeConverter().toSVG(new GeneralPath(
                    new Rectangle(10,10,50,50)));
             
            path.setContent(svg.getAttribute("d"));
        break;
        
        default: 
            return null;
    }
    
    return path;
}
```

Unfortunately this only works when I don't process the "rect" case, else it just shows nothing. I haven't figured out why this is the case.

As an alternative, I'm trying a custom ImageLoaderFactory, but I can't figure out how to include the imports. I have this line for instance:

```
import com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageLoaderFactory;
```

But it says "The type com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageLoaderFactory is not accessible" and doesn't show me any hints in eclipse on how to fix this. I have already included all the JavaFX packages in maven and Eclipse recognized the namespace, but shows this error when importing it.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: com.sun.JavaFX apis are intended to be private APIs used by the internal JavaFX implementation, not application code. Their use is not recommended.

Comment: Probably, the module system hides these com.sun.javafx classes from your app.  If you try to run the JavaFX libs off the class path instead of the module path (not recommended or supported), then it might work.  Similarly, if you open the relevant module to your app.  Read up on the Java module system if you don’t know how to do this.

Comment: You can display an svg in a JavaFX WebView.